# Content search webpart is not returning values of single line of text in SP2013

Tags: search, content

I am working with content search webpart wich is not displaying values of multiple line of text even in 'Twolines' display template.  I have created a new site column with type single line text and added site column in content type of that library. Then add a new item with value in single line of text. Do a full crawl, still it is showing blank. Can anyone please help on these. I have been trying for this for last 2 days.

Comment: If anyone came across thus issue, please help